# How can I get Outlook to restore previously-open message windows when restarting?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, reboot

So Outlook crashed on me yesterday...

...Ok, so *that's* not terribly interesting. But what happened next was: there was a "Restart" option on the resulting crash dialog. When I clicked it, Outlook re-opened *along with all of my previously-open messages!*

Well, surprise, surprise - Outlook missed an opportunity to annoy me!

But now I'm curious: is there a way to make this happen *intentionally?* I do enjoy closing Outlook now and then, to reboot or just to get it out of my hair. But losing track of the messages I'd been reading isn't much fun. I suppose I could flag them or something, but that's tedious - I'd rather just close the app on a whim, knowing I could pick back up where I left off later.

So: is there an option for this somewhere, buried deep within the bowels of Outlook's labyrinthine Options dialog? Or failing that... Any good tips on making Outlook *crash on demand?*

Comment: If you kill Outlook from, say, Process Explorer what is the behaviour on restart? Does it give you the Restart dialogue?

Comment: @Rory: no... But you gave me an idea: I wonder if Outlook is using the Restart Manager to accomplish this...

Comment: Killing Outlook process with, say, Process Explorer doesn't return Outlook to previous state; However, File -> Exit, and re-launching Outlook.exe with /restore switch _does_!

Comment: I tried the file>exit and then re-open with /restore, and no luck? I had one extra window open with outlook and it didn't get restored. I'm using outlook 2016 though.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps use the /restore switch on the command line:

http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-restore-open-email-windows-in-Outlook-after-a-crash-like-Firefox-restores-tabs-and-windows

Comment: DrClown - Please copy the important content from the linked page, to your answer, to prevent [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: FTA: Use the 'restore' switch / flag. Your shortcut's target should look something like this:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /restore`  Or, for one time use, you can just run that from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

1) make a shortcut to the Outlook application on your desktop (you may already have one there)

2) right-click the shortcut and choose the last menu item "Properties"

3) in the field labeled "Target" you should see a file path to where Outlook is installed on your PC. Click to the end of that path and add /restore

It should look something like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /restore

Now when you launch Outlook via that shortcut it will restore all open items. Really useful if your machine crashes or Windows force restarts based on a critical update.

Comment: This is just a way to automate DrClown’s answer from 2½ years ago. Also, the existing shortcut to Outlook probably doesn’t have an editable “Target” field.

Comment: Yes, which is an improvement on Dr Clown's answer.  Thanks November man.  He's right the existing shortcut doesn't have an editable target field, but since you tell us to create one, I can use that.

Comment: any suggestions for outlook 2016?

Answer (score 4):

There is a new Outlook setting that does this, under General->Start up options: "When Outlook opens" - available options are:

- Ask me if I want to restore previous items (default)
- Never restore previous items (old behavior)
- Always restore previous items (what you want)

I was looking for it and stumbled across this post. The link is here: https://office-watch.com/2020/outlook-gets-better-restart-and-reopen-options/

Comment: Fantastic! Granted, a full decade later and years after I stopped using Outlook in frustration... But a good option none the less; thanks for taking the time to write about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to [hibernate the process to disk](https://superuser.com/questions/288460/how-to-free-up-memory-fully-hibernating-a-process).

If it works, you get your messages. If it doesn't work and crashes, you get your messages back.

Unless it completely doesn't work, this should be a win-win situation... :)

Answer (score 0):

I closed a window where I prepared a calendar appointment and by mistake chose "Don't save".

Amazingly this helped:

Go to Deleted items in Outlook, then on top there was an option "Recover items recently removed from this folder", it had a list of all kinds of stuff dating several months back. My closed appointment (basically an unsent email) was there.