# Where does Outlook store the previously-open windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

Sometimes, Outlook will reopen the previously-open windows if you start it with the /restore option after a crash.

Does anyone know where Outlook actually stores this information? I'd like to make a backup of it, just in case something goes wrong after relaunching Outlook.

For web browsers like Firefox and Safari, there are the corresponding session files in %appdata%, but for Outlook, I couldn't figure out any such files.

Comment: Should be in the registry. Don't know where though.

Comment: There is really not a lot to store. (a) Flag - not closed properly (b) Email open at the time - Email ID.  So just an Outlook Registry entry.

Comment: Do you have any idea where exactly in the registry to find this info?

Comment: @tajmahal any luck finding which registry key?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with LPChip, it should be in the registry, but have not found any document tells where the exact location is. [Where does Outlook store list of open items?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/where-does-outlook-store-list-of-open-items/a8a7a098-34b5-4430-afe8-359d84514e31)

Found a similar thread talking about the same issue: [How can I get Outlook to restore previously-open message windows when restarting?](https://superuser.com/questions/193464/how-can-i-get-outlook-to-restore-previously-open-message-windows-when-restarting) but also did not get the exact location. For your reference.

Besides, for Outlook desktop client, the %appdata% stores some other Outlook settings, you could get them via this article: [Find and transfer Outlook data files from one computer to another](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-transfer-outlook-data-files-from-one-computer-to-another-0996ece3-57c6-49bc-977b-0d1892e2aacc?ocmsassetid=hp010354943&correlationid=41d7520d-8669-4d8d-8df7-07a79f8e0460&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Comment: any luck finding which registry key?

Answer (score 2):

It's not located in plaintext, but it *is* in the registry, somewhere under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\[Version]\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\`. Where exactly in there I don't know, but here's how you can be sure:

1. Close Outlook with windows open
2. Export the key
3. Open Outlook again, open different windows, then close Outlook again
4. Import the previously exported key (don't forget to backup the registry!)
5. Open Outlook again, and let Outlook restore windows. Sure enough, it restores the windows that were open when outlook was closed the first time.

What exactly in that key is responsible for restoring the windows is hard to tell - it might be different for every user for all I know. But hopefully this helps someone along. (credits to Regshot for helping me find the key!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What exactly in my answer is unclear? The question was where the information is stored. I provided a registry key where it's stored and a way to verify that it's actually stored there. I'm open to improving my answer, but I'm a little confused as to _what_ I should improve (other than a word that I somehow mixed up but that doesn't change the substance of the answer).

Comment: @BenjaminKrausseDB do you know of a way to get the previous keys from a past session, about three sessions ago?

Comment: @AlexF your best bet would be to see if there's a system restore point from that time frame. A system restore would be simple, would work, but probably be overkill. Otherwise you can check for previous versions of the HKCU registry hive (stored in %UserProfile%\Ntuser.dat as a hidden file, probably also an operating system protected file) or use Nir Sofer's RegistryChangesView and load a shadow copy.